# Maven Checkstyle Inline Filter Configuration

Tags: maven, checkstyle

I see that the Checkstyle Maven plugin allows for inline configuration of modules:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/inline-checker-config.html

I understand how to configure filters in an external file, but I'd like the configuration to be inline so I can use it in a parent POM and share the configuration for all my projects. I see that filters are a form of modules, but I don't understand the relationship between *filters as a module*, and *module configuration* well enough to get started.

**Can I add suppression filters to the Checkstyle Maven plugin's configuration in the POM, without the use of an external file ?**

For example referring to [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/suppressions-filter.html), can I inline the configuration defined in `checkstyle-suppressions.xml` inside the pom itself?

edit: Responding to comments, yes I mean modules and filters exclusively in the Checkstyle context.

Comment: The terms `filters` and `modules` in the question can lead to a bit of confusion since they have meaning both in the 'maven' context as well as 'checkstyle'.  If I've interpreted your description correctly, it seems that you are talking about `filters` and `modules` in the context of checkstyle. Can you please confirm (and also add a note to the question itself) ? Might be helpful for future readers.

Comment: SO-ers, http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html is a useful link to read more about 'checkstyle' filters and modules.